# Devise Rails reset_password method is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

According to [the documentation](https://rubydoc.info/github/heartcombo/devise/master/Devise/Models/Recoverable) the method reset_password of the Devise gem of Ruby should work like this:

```
User.find(1).reset_password('password123', 'password123')
```

This method is returning true, but when I try to login with this user and the new password (or even with the old password) the app won't let me and log "Completed 401 Unauthorized".

Also I am using omniauth to be able to login socially.

Comment: Do you need to `save` the record after to apply the changes?

Comment: have you added before_action in your ApplicationController that requires user authentication?